# NERDTree does not open in the directory from which macvim was opened

Tags: mac, macvim

I upgraded my macvim to 7.3 recently and I can no longer open nerdtree or netw in the directory in which macvim was opened, it always opens in my home directory.

For example,

If I open macvim in /users/me/test/project dir, I want the NERDTree root to be /Users/me/test/project and not /Users/me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [Janus "MacVim distro"](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) has [some gvimrc configs](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/blob/master/gvimrc) to get NERDTree directories right.

Works fine for me with MacVim 7.3.